# Flutter: Passing list from one page to another page

Tags: list, flutter

I working on a flutter project. I want to pass list from one page to another page. but it not working out for me

```
List list;

    articleCall save = await Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute<articleCall>(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return new AddArticleDialog(list);
                },
        -----------

        class AddArticleDialog extends StatefulWidget {

            List ls=[];

          AddArticleDialog({this.ls});
          @override
          AddArticleDialogState createState() => new AddArticleDialogState();
        }
```

It says me the error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Please help

Thanks,
Sathish

Comment: remove `{` and `}` from `AddArticleDialog({this.ls});`

Comment: `return new AddArticleDialog(list);`  - should be - `return new AddArticleDialog(ls: list);`

Comment: on my IDE Udara

Comment: It worked anmol.Thanks so much.

Comment: do you **really** want to have a parameter named `ls`? does it say anything to anyone? also what is the purpose on such named parameter if you have only one? just remove `{` and `}` and make it positional

Answer (score 0):

When braces `{}` are used on constructor parameters, it will become named parameters as mentioned in the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters).

Having the constructor as

```dart
List? ls=[]; // List should be nullable since the argument is optional
AddArticleDialog({this.ls});
```

will require it to use an identifier for the argument.

```dart
return AddArticleDialog(ls: list);
```